# Rewriting Angular 4 service to angular 7 caused Rxjs problem

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I am having difficulty in rewriting  angular 4 service to angular 7 compact able code

Angular 4 code :

```
  public load(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.cache<Product[]>(() => this.products,
      (val: Observable<Product[]>) => this.products = val,
      () => this.http
        .get(this.apiUrl + "/products")
        .map((response) => response.json()
          .map((item) => {
            let model = new Product();
            model.updateFrom(item);
            return model;
          })));

  }
```

What i have tried so far rewriting it to support angular 7 by using `httpClient` instead of `http`  :

```
  public all(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.cache<Product[]>(() => this.products,
      (val: Observable<Product[]>) => this.products = val,
      () => this.http
        .get(this.apiUrl + "/products")
        .pipe(map((response: Product) => {
          let result: Product[] = [];
          let model = new Product();
          model.updateFrom(response);
          result.push(model);
          return result;
        }))
          );

  }
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. looked through the doc  and other threads but couldn't find an answer. Please give your suggestions

Comment: So what problem do you have? You didn't say what's wrong.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If I understand it well you just want to check code?

Comment: @JosefKatič yes , to see if this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't mention what problem you have, I assume that you are having problem with mapping the result returned from the HTTP request.

The result returned from `get` request should be an array that needs to be converted to an array of `Product`s. Therefore it should be:

```
...

() => this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/products")
       .pipe(
          map((response: Array<any>) => {

            let result:  Array<Product> = [];

            response.forEach((responseModel) => {
                let model = new Product();
                model.updateFrom(responseModel);
                result.push(model);
            });


            return result;
         })
       )

...
```